# Java Date - Leap year - strange behavior

Tags: java, date, datetime

So I've got this kind of strange problem with Java's Date.

The entry-point for this problem are 2 String dates startDate("30 Jan 2016") and endate ""29 Jan 2017".

The problem is a little bit more complex,but I've summed it up just to this case.

What I have to do is get an 1 year schedule exactly like the one from bellow starting with this data.

The table contains for each month: first day, last day, and days between those 2 days.

**Expected results:**

/**

- Sat Jan 30 00:00:00 GMT 2016 - Sun Feb 28 23:59:59 GMT 2016 - 30
- Mon Feb 29 00:00:00 GMT 2016 - Tue Mar 29 23:59:59 BST 2016 - 30
- Wed Mar 30 00:00:00 BST 2016 - Fri Apr 29 23:59:59 BST 2016 - 31
- Sat Apr 30 00:00:00 BST 2016 - Sun May 29 23:59:59 BST 2016 - 30
- Mon May 30 00:00:00 BST 2016 - Wed Jun 29 23:59:59 BST 2016 - 31
- Thu Jun 30 00:00:00 BST 2016 - Fri Jul 29 23:59:59 BST 2016 - 30
- Sat Jul 30 00:00:00 BST 2016 - Mon Aug 29 23:59:59 BST 2016 - 31
- Tue Aug 30 00:00:00 BST 2016 - Thu Sep 29 23:59:59 BST 2016 - 31
- Fri Sep 30 00:00:00 BST 2016 - Sat Oct 29 23:59:59 BST 2016 - 30
- Sun Oct 30 00:00:00 BST 2016 - Tue Nov 29 23:59:59 GMT 2016 - 31
- Wed Nov 30 00:00:00 GMT 2016 - Thu Dec 29 23:59:59 GMT 2016 - 30
- Fri Dec 30 00:00:00 GMT 2016 - Sun Jan 29 23:59:59 GMT 2017 - 31

*/

**My results are**

Sat Jan 30 00:00:00 EET 2016 ::::: Sun Feb 28 23:59:59 EET 2016 ::::: 29

Mon Feb 29 00:00:00 EET 2016 ::::: Mon Mar 28 23:59:59 EEST 2016 ::::: 28

Tue Mar 29 00:00:00 EEST 2016 ::::: Thu Apr 28 23:59:59 EEST 2016 ::::: 30

Fri Apr 29 00:00:00 EEST 2016 ::::: Sat May 28 23:59:59 EEST 2016 ::::: 29

Sun May 29 00:00:00 EEST 2016 ::::: Tue Jun 28 23:59:59 EEST 2016 ::::: 30

Wed Jun 29 00:00:00 EEST 2016 ::::: Thu Jul 28 23:59:59 EEST 2016 ::::: 29

Fri Jul 29 00:00:00 EEST 2016 ::::: Sun Aug 28 23:59:59 EEST 2016 ::::: 30

Mon Aug 29 00:00:00 EEST 2016 ::::: Wed Sep 28 23:59:59 EEST 2016 ::::: 30

Thu Sep 29 00:00:00 EEST 2016 ::::: Fri Oct 28 23:59:59 EEST 2016 ::::: 29

Sat Oct 29 00:00:00 EEST 2016 ::::: Mon Nov 28 23:59:59 EET 2016 ::::: 31

Tue Nov 29 00:00:00 EET 2016 ::::: Wed Dec 28 23:59:59 EET 2016 ::::: 29

Thu Dec 29 00:00:00 EET 2016 ::::: Sat Jan 28 23:59:59 EET 2017 ::::: 30

So I’m not sure if this happens because of the February month or because 2016 was a leap year that included 29th of February.

What am I missing? I have the same problem run multiple test cases and all others are OK, but this.

I've also tried to do this with Javas 8 LocalDate and LocalDateTime and I get the exactly same results.

Here is my code

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String startDate = "30 Jan 2016";
        String endDate = "29 Jan 2017"; // current not using this ?!
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

        Date start = formatter.parse(startDate);

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            Date end = DateUtils.addMonths(start, 1);
            end = DateUtils.addSeconds(end, -1);
            items.add(new Item(start, end));
            start = DateUtils.addMonths(start, 1);
        }

        items.forEach(item -> {
            System.out.println(item.getStart() + " ::::: " + item.getEnd() + " ::::: " + getDifferenceDays(item.getStart(), item.getEnd()));
        });

    }

    public static long getDifferenceDays(Date d1, Date d2) {
        return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1.toInstant(), d2.toInstant());
    }

}
```

- Item Class

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Item {
    Date start;
    Date end;

    public Item(Date start, Date end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Date getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(Date start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public Date getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(Date end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "start=" + start +
                ", end=" + end +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, for starters, you should not use `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. They're troublesome. Use classes from `java.time` instead.

Comment: As I've said... I've used  Javas 8 LocalDate and LocalDateTime  and I get the same behavior.

Comment: Did you try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html; setting a zone. Oh I see DateUtils is an external library, recall my comment regarding it.

Comment: DateUtils is from import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils; I'm not getting it what exactly are you meaning by  the ZonedDateTime class. Still O changed my computers date to GTM and not I'm getting the same timezones, but the date behaviour is the same.

Comment: PeterMmm is correct: you're not using DateUtils correctly.  But more to the point, if you're on Java 8 or higher, you're *MUCH* better off using the new Java "time" instead.  SUGGESTION: Please try Ole V.V's advice.  If it works, please "Upvote" and "Accept" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

Since you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, I recommend that you stick to that and leave the old classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` alone. Then you also don’t need the Apache `DateUtils`. The `ChronoUnit` enum is from java.time.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM u", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    String startDateString = "30 Jan 2016";
    LocalDate originalStartDate
            = LocalDate.parse(startDateString, dateFormatter);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        LocalDate startDate = originalStartDate.plusMonths(i);
        LocalDate nextStartDate = originalStartDate.plusMonths(i + 1);
        LocalDate endDate = nextStartDate.minusDays(1);
        long differenceDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, nextStartDate);
        
        System.out.format("%s - %s : %d%n", startDate, endDate, differenceDays);
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2016-01-30 - 2016-02-28 : 30
> 2016-02-29 - 2016-03-29 : 30
> 2016-03-30 - 2016-04-29 : 31
> 2016-04-30 - 2016-05-29 : 30
> 2016-05-30 - 2016-06-29 : 31
> 2016-06-30 - 2016-07-29 : 30
> 2016-07-30 - 2016-08-29 : 31
> 2016-08-30 - 2016-09-29 : 31
> 2016-09-30 - 2016-10-29 : 30
> 2016-10-30 - 2016-11-29 : 31
> 2016-11-30 - 2016-12-29 : 30
> 2016-12-30 - 2017-01-29 : 31
> ```

### What went wrong in your code?

There are a couple of reasons behind your observed unexpected results.

1. When you add a month to January 30, you get February 29 as you had expected. In a non-leap year you would have got February 28. When you add another month to February 29, you get March 29. Is it surprising when you think about it? In a non-leap year you would have got March 28, so 2016 being a leap year actually helped you get *closer* to your desired result. In my code I solve this problem by adding the correct number of months to the original start date rather than adding one month to the previous start date.
2. As PeterMmm already said, `ChronoUnit.DAYS.Between()` counts full 24 hours days. Any partial day is discarded. Even 23 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds. From Sat Jan 30 00:00:00 EET 2016 to Sun Feb 28 23:59:59 EET 2016 is 30 days 23 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds, so the result you get is 30 days. In my code I solve the problem by counting the days until the start of the next item.

As an aside: From Mon Feb 29 00:00:00 EET 2016 to Mon Mar 28 23:59:59 EEST 2016, because of transistion to summer time (DST) is only 28 days **22 hours** 59 minutes 59 seconds. So abstaining from subtracting a second would not solve your problem in this case.

Comment: Thank you !!!  I haven't look at it like that. Date/Time/Leap years are something tricky in programming. Glad that Java 8 with java.time package solved a lot of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
end = DateUtils.addSeconds(end, -1);
```

isn't necessary. Or do

```
end = DateUtils.addSeconds(end, 0);
```

have a look at [between()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) documentation.
Second parameter is **exclusive**. That means, your second parameter does not reach the end of day and so a day less is counted (only full 24h days are counted).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```java
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 30);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 30);

Function<YearMonth, LocalDate> addMonthFunction = ym -> ym
    .atDay(Math.min(startDate.getDayOfMonth(), ym.lengthOfMonth()));

long months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(startDate, endDate);
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.from(startDate);
Stream.iterate(yearMonth, ym -> ym.plusMonths(1))
    .limit(months)
    .map(addMonthFunction)
    .map(LocalDate::atStartOfDay)
    .map(date -> {
        LocalDateTime end = addMonthFunction.apply(YearMonth.from(date.plusMonths(1)))
            .atStartOfDay()
            .minusSeconds(1);
        long between = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date, end) + 1;
        return String.format("%s to %s (%s days)", date, end, between);
    })
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The idea is that each next date always falls on the 30th day of the month (or, more precisely, the same day-of-month as the start date), except if that would be an invalid date.

I used `LocalDate`s here, but you could make it timezone-sensitive by using `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks.